# How to restart kafka Stream application in uncaught exception handler?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to restart my kafka Stream application after catching exception in uncaught exception handler.how to do that?

Comment: Just start the Java process again... If you didn't change the group/application ID, the offset will be picked back up from the latest commit

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, you would typically send such exceptions to a separate topic called a "dead letter queue". That's less complex than implementing "retry logic"

Comment: @cricket_007 i want to restart the stream also... because it will be continuously picking up messages for processing

Comment: Kafka is append-only... It'll already continuously process from the end of the topic. Are you trying to always restart from the beginning of a topic? If so, then set the application ID just to some UUID number

Comment: @cricket_007 no no i am just trying to keep my application up in case of exceptions..i dont want yo restart it..thanks for you answer it was really helpful :)

Comment: Let's say you tried to process a message, then it failed with some uncaught exception. You then changed the processing code, and restarted the app, it should continue from approximately the same message depending on how frequently you are committing offsets. Or you just catch all possible exceptions and let the app continue on. Of course, you still need account for hardware failure, so youll need to run the app on many machines for it to really "always be running"

Comment: @cricket_007 in my application, scenario is - Messages will be coming continuously from upstream component, failed Message will be caught and forwarded to exception topic and logging will be done. And problem i was facing was as soon as exception occurres, my application was getting jammed. I tried uncaughtexceptionHandler and its working now

Comment: You can either restart the JVM, or you (1) `KafkaStreams#close()` the current instance, create a new `KafkaStreams` object, and restart using the new object `KafkaStreams#start()`.

Answer (score 2):

If your application (or, more precisely, an instance of your application) reached the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in Kafka's Streams API, it's past the point of no return -- you can't restart your application from there.

The UEH is meant to help you gracefully shutdown your application instance, e.g. by writing an informative log message, by sending a metric to your monitoring setup, and so on.

Kafka Streams applications are normal Java/Scala applications, which means they are running as JVM processes.  You can use any tool that is capable of managing such processes to keep them up and running, to restart them in case of failure, etc.  A popular example nowadays is Kubernetes, but also more old-school technologies such as `supervisord` work well.